# ESP32 FreeRTOS non-blocking semaphore in task

Tags: c, semaphore, interrupt, esp32, freertos

I have a task that waits for a semaphore to run. Then it has to go in an infinite loop to control a motor position.

I would like to break this second loop when the stop button is pressed. Is there any way to call `xSemaphoreTake()` to break from the second loop but not block the while loop of the control?

Let me try to give some code example:

```
void startTaskFunction(void *params){ //this is the function
    while (true)
    {
        xSemaphoreTake(StartSema,portMAX_DELAY); //which in order to start waits this Semaphore to be Given
        while(true){

            //do some logic to controll a motor and keep it steady

            /////to stop this while on some stop button if i use the next i think it will 
            //stop and waits on the first run of the loop so there is no control
            xSemaphoreTake(StopSema,portMAX_DELAY);
            break;
            // if i wrap it in an if condition i think it is the same isn't it?

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, I would appreciate it if you could also upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to [take the semaphore](https://www.freertos.org/a00122.html) without a delay and if successful, break out of the loop:

```c
void startTaskFunction(void *params)
{
    while (true) {
        xSemaphoreTake(StartSema, portMAX_DELAY);
        while (true) {
            //do some logic to controll a motor and keep it steady

            if (xSemaphoreTake(StopSema, 0) == pdTRUE) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```